# Custom Slack Function in Deno Fails : Event Dispatch Failed Error

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-bot

I'm developing a custom Slack function using the Deno Slack SDK to process onboarding data. The function aims to determine relevant channels based on the new member's details and add them accordingly. However, when running the function, it fails, and I receive an event_dispatch_failed error. Below are the details of my implementation and the logs I've received.
Function Description:

The "Process Onboarding Data" function is designed to:

```
Determine relevant channels for a new member based on their interests.
Add the new member to these channels automatically.
```

Code Snippets:

```
import { DefineFunction, Schema, SlackFunction } from "deno-slack-sdk/mod.ts";
import { determineChannels } from "./channel_mapping.ts";

export const OnboardingFunctionDefinition = DefineFunction({
   callback_id: "onboarding_function",
   title: "Process Onboarding Data",
   description: "Determine relevant channels and add the new member based on their interests",
   source_file: "functions/onboarding_function_definition.ts",
   input_parameters: {
       properties: {
           country: { type: Schema.types.string, description: "Country of the new member" },
           city: { type: Schema.types.string, description: "City of the new member" },
     
         
          
           recipient: { type: Schema.slack.types.user_id, description: "Recipient user ID" }
       }
    
   output_parameters: {
       properties: {
           success: { type: Schema.types.boolean, description: "Indicates if the member was successfully added to relevant channels" },
       },
       required: ["success"],
   }
});

// Function logic 

export default SlackFunction(OnboardingFunctionDefinition, async ({ inputs, client }) => {
   // const channels = determineChannels(inputs);
   const channels = ["iran"];
   let allSuccess = true;

   for (const name of channels) {
       // const channelName = await getChannelIdByName(client, name);
       const channelName = await getChannelIdByName(client, name);
       if (!channelName) {
           console.log(`Channel ${name} not found.`);
           allSuccess = false;
           continue;
       }

       const success = await joinChannelIfNotAlreadyJoined(client, channelName, inputs.recipient);
       allSuccess = allSuccess && success;
   }

   return { outputs: { success: allSuccess } };
});

async function joinChannelIfNotAlreadyJoined(client, channelId, userId) {
   if (!channelId) return false;

   try {
       const joinResponse = await client.conversations.join({ channel: channelId });
       if (!joinResponse.ok && joinResponse.error !== 'already_in_channel') {
           throw new Error(`Error joining channel ${channelId}: ${joinResponse.error}`);
       }

       await client.conversations.invite({ channel: channelId, users: userId });
       return true;
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error.message);
       return false;
   }
}

async function getChannelIdByName(client, channelName) {
   let cursor;
   do {
       const result = await client.conversations.list({ cursor, limit: 200 }).catch(error => {
           console.error("Failed to fetch channel list:", error);
           return null;
       });

       console.log("Fetched channels:", result.channels.map(c => c.name)); // Log fetched channel names

       if (result && result.ok) {
           const channel = result.channels.find(c => c.name === channelName);
           if (channel) {
               console.log(`Found channel: ${channelName} with ID: ${channel.id}`); // Confirm channel found
               return channel.id;
           }
           cursor = result.response_metadata?.next_cursor;
       } else {
           break;
       }
   } while (cursor);

   console.error(`Channel ${channelName} not found.`);
   return null;
}
```

Error Logs:

```
Found channel: Iran with ID: C0999999999
2024-02-11 12:24:29 [error] [Fn06J8AT49A6] (Trace=Tr06J8BVBFJ6) Function 'Process Onboarding Data' (app function) failed
        event_dispatch_failed
2024-02-11 12:24:29 [error] [Wf06J1MRFXRU] (Trace=Tr06J8BVBFJ6) Workflow step 'Process Onboarding Data' failed
```